# List Iterator Access Violation

Tags: c++, list, access-violation

I have a `list` of pointers to `SomeClass` objects in a `Main` class. Whilst in `Main` I can iterate over the `list` using `list::begin()` and `list::end()`.

When I do the same from an instance of `SomeClass` (bearing in mind that the `list` is a public member of the `Main` class) I get the following exception:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf0ad.

I am fairly new to coding in C++ coming from a Python background, so I apologise if something doesn't make sense.

Here is an example of the situation:

**EDIT:** The Main class codes is not actually inside the constructor, its in a method called `InitialiseObjects()`.

**EDIT:** The exceptions comes from within the `list::being()` method with the line `return (iterator(_Nextnode(_Myhead), this));`

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Main
{
public:
    Main::InitialiseObjects()
    {
        // Execution starts here
        SomeClass someClass = new SomClass(this);
        someClasses.push_back(someClass);

        // This works fine
        for (list<SomeClass*>::iterator it = someClasses.begin(); it != someClasses.end(); it++)
            ...

        someClass->AFunction();
    }
    list<SomeClass*> someClasses;
}

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass::SomeClass(Main *main) : main(main) {}
    void SomeClass::AFunction()
    {
        // This will not work throwing the aformentioned error
        for (list<SomeClass*>::iterator it = main->someClasses.begin(); it != main->someClasses.end(); it++)
            ...
    }
private:
    Main *main;
}
```

Comment: Please post the real code; the above code doesn’t compile.

Comment: How do you pass *main to SomeClass?

Comment: @Koray: `SomeClass someClass = new SomClass(this);`.

Comment: The real code is large and over 2 .h and 2 .cpp files. I pass *main to `SomeClass` via the constructor.

Comment: Indeed, the devil is in the details.

Comment: The code above (not considering it's incomplete and therefore won't even compile) is not the reason for the crash. Aren't you by any chance deleting members from the list during the iteration?

Comment: @Marcus: Where do you call `InitialiseObjects`? If you call that function in the constructor, the problem remains the same.

Comment: I am not deleting elements from the list, and `InitialiseObjects` is not being called from within the constructor. Initially I though that the error might be that only `Main` can iterate over its own member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf0ad.
```

I think that was `0xbaadf00d` until you overwrote something in it, which indicates uninitialized heap memory. So, maybe you're dereferencing a non-existant `Main*`?  E.g. `main->someClasses.begin()` may throw your exception, if `main` wasn't initialized yet.
And indeed, this is the problem in your code. `someClass->AFunction();` calls the function **while you're inside the `Main`-constructor**. As such, `this` will not be completely valid yet, so you can't use it inside the `AFunction`.

Comment: I made a mistake, that codes is actually called from method and not the constructor, I have edited my code.

Comment: It probably is location 0xbaadf00d + offset 0xa0.  But I'm only guessing.

Comment: ... and that would be `Main::someClasses`, probably. Ergo it's probably the `main` pointer that's not initialized. Use-after-free?

Comment: Your answer was in fact the case, the pointer to `Main` was not initialised, but I couldn't see it because the code is quite complicated, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you remain inside the `Main` constructor, the `this` instance is *not yet fully initialised*!

Trying to access the instance from elsewhere leads to undefined behaviour. This is happening here since you are accessing this unfinished instance from within `SomeClass`.

Comment: While formally correct, it's definitely not the problem here. All members of `SomeClass` are constructed by the time they are accessed and if `SomeClass` does not have any virtual methods, there is nothing else that wouldn't be initialized in it.

Comment: When you're in the body of the constructor, not all class invariants may have been established, but all subobjects have been (indeed, fully) initialised.

Comment: My fault, the code in reality is not in the constructor it is located with a method `Main::InitialiseObjects()`, I have modified my question.

Comment: @Jan: It's not `SomeClass` that isn't fully constructed, but `Main` is the problem, as my answer points out.

Comment: @Xeo: Small braino. The argument still stands though—`Main` is constructed enough that the use will not fail.

Comment: @Jan You are merely assuming that. We have no way of telling what the compiler does for optimisations which may break your assumption. I’ve seen stranger things. Of course, the point is moot now that Marcus has said that the code isn’t run in the constructor.